# Serializing File Output

Tags: performance-tuning, output-formatting, files-and-directories

Right now my code is something like

```
Put[
    Table[
        *some calculations*
        {SparseArray[matrix], coordinates}, 

        {i, 1, numIterations}
    ],
    destinationFile
]
```

As far as I can tell, this requires that the `Table` finish evaluating in full, which ends up storing a list of `numIterations` copies of my matrices and coordinates, before it can write those to a file en mass. The issue with this is that I'm working on a research system with very tight memory usage restrictions. This tends to run over the memory cap before it finishes executing. What I would *like* to be able to do is serialize that output (replacing `Table` by `Do`) such that it never has to store more than one copy of the matrix and the coordinates in memory.

Using `PutAppend` doesn't work because I later need to be able to read this back in as a list in another notebook, and `PutAppend` places newlines after everything so I can't actually re-create the output format from `Put` manually. Are there ways to do this that aren't too horrible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (without much trouble) incrementally construct this via [`OpenWrite`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpenWrite.html), [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString.html) and [`WriteString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WriteString.html) / [`WriteLine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WriteLine.html).

Unfortunately I'm not sure whether this will actually solve your memory problem, but here you are:

```
In[91]:= mxStep[i_] := RandomReal[1, {i, 25}]

In[92]:= $file = CreateFile[];

In[93]:= $steps = 2;
$outputStream = OpenWrite@$file;
WriteLine[$outputStream, "{"];
Do[
  WriteString[$outputStream, ToString[mxStep[i], InputForm]];
  If[i < $steps, WriteLine[$outputStream, ","]],
  {i, $steps}
  ];
WriteLine[$outputStream, "}"];
Close@$outputStream;
Get@$file

Out[99]= {{{0.0710782, 0.295713, 0.358965, 0.403495, 0.91221, 
   0.069269, 0.017493, 0.545457, 0.809002, 0.0733453, 0.531084, 
   0.0770646, 0.910339, 0.383475, 0.543017, 0.866425, 0.198109, 
   0.211237, 0.0802018, 0.444478, 0.9013, 0.47711, 0.348436, 0.822508,
    0.124759}}, {{0.440658, 0.00978242, 0.979155, 0.98225, 0.705378, 
   0.00294301, 0.774715, 0.354214, 0.391704, 0.34864, 0.467632, 
   0.960777, 0.47898, 0.910341, 0.174031, 0.267939, 0.855774, 
   0.113104, 0.102345, 0.92824, 0.488277, 0.28265, 0.73727, 0.345047, 
   0.0844829}, {0.50581, 0.5225, 0.648322, 0.289525, 0.617664, 
   0.420004, 0.343535, 0.028053, 0.620158, 0.107122, 0.445789, 
   0.43033, 0.0933331, 0.733211, 0.161032, 0.873127, 0.974476, 
   0.131961, 0.543887, 0.736284, 0.686062, 0.525942, 0.46038, 
   0.613206, 0.836906}}}
```